# Generating the token for external application for Graph API end points in C# by passing the user credentials

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I have an external application which uses a common azure user account to access the GraphAPI token with out any user prompt.The gran type used is password and when tried to send the request,the response received is Bad reqeust. Any idea how to get the valid token for the user to perform the transactions using Graph API without prompting the user to authorize.The application has all the delegated permissions.

Here is my code

```
var tenant = "my tenant";
var clientID = "client id";
var resource = "https://graph.microsoft.com";
var secret = "client secret";
List < KeyValuePair < string, string >> vals = new
List < KeyValuePair < string, string >> ();
vals.Add(new KeyValuePair < string, string > ("grant_type",
    "password"));
vals.Add(new KeyValuePair < string, string > ("client_id", clientID));
vals.Add(new KeyValuePair < string, string > ("client_secret", secret));
vals.Add(new KeyValuePair < string, string > ("resource", resource));
vals.Add(new KeyValuePair < string, string > ("username",
    "user@tenant.onmicrosoft.com"));
vals.Add(new KeyValuePair < string, string > ("password", "pwd"));
vals.Add(new KeyValuePair < string, string > ("scope", "openid"));
string url =
    https: //login.microsoftonline.com/tenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/token";
HttpClient hc = new HttpClient();
HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(vals);
HttpResponseMessage hrm = await hc.PostAsync(url, content);
```

Kindly help me what I am doing wrong and how  to get the token silently

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to leverage adal.net to get the token instead of forging everything manually. You'll get easier and higher level API, community support, support from Microsoft, samples and a lot of other things that are going to make things easier.
Here is one [blog post about it](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/07/08/using-adal-net-to-authenticate-users-via-usernamepassword/) the [github project](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet) and [some documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-libraries).

Comment: Thanks so much Baywet !.I will try to implement the adal.net and will see if I can be able to get it work as my intention is to access the API without any user intervention to perform all the transactions

Comment: feel free to ask another question if you run into challenges. And don't forget to mark as answer to help others :)

Answer (score 0):

The proper request body of the Resource Owner Password Grant looks like this (line-breaks for readability):

```
resource=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F
&client_id=<client id>
&grant_type=password
&username=xxx@xxx.onmicrosoft.com
&password=<password>
&scope=openid";
```

A couple of things I see wrong in your code:

1. Your `resource` URL isn't URL Encoded
2. Your URL doesn't have a valid tenant `https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant.onmicrosoft.com`. Unless your tenant is actually *named* `tenant.onmicrosoft.com` it will fail.

Try this instead:

```
var tenant = "common";
var clientID = "client id";
var resource = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("https://graph.microsoft.com");
var secret = "client secret";

List < KeyValuePair < string, string >> vals = new List < KeyValuePair < string, string >> ();

vals.Add(new KeyValuePair < string, string > ("grant_type", "password"));
vals.Add(new KeyValuePair < string, string > ("client_id", clientID));
vals.Add(new KeyValuePair < string, string > ("client_secret", secret));
vals.Add(new KeyValuePair < string, string > ("resource", resource));
vals.Add(new KeyValuePair < string, string > ("username", "user@tenant.onmicrosoft.com"));
vals.Add(new KeyValuePair < string, string > ("password", "pwd"));
vals.Add(new KeyValuePair < string, string > ("scope", "openid"));

string url = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/token";
HttpClient hc = new HttpClient();
HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(vals);
HttpResponseMessage hrm = await hc.PostAsync(url, content);
```

---

Please note that using the Resource Owner Password Grant is *very strongly discouraged*. To call it a security hole does it a huge diservice. It is the digital equivilent of putting your password on a PostIt note.

If you need a user in context you should be using the Authorization Code Grant and maintaining a Refresh Token for long-term access. If you don't need a user in context then you should use the Client Credentials Grant.

Comment: Thanks Marc ! Yes I do have a valid tenant however I will try adding the encoded URL and also the Authorization code grant since my external application does need the user context for performing the Graph api file transactions.